# update no doctrine 2

Tags: php

Para realizar um update no symfony usando doctrine2. Eu sei que primeiro consultamos a entidadade pelo id para saber se existe. Caso ela exista
temos que modificar o objeto retornado pela consulta. 
Depois modificamos este objeto com modificadores de acesso. 
Existe algum helper para passar as propriedades de um objeto para o objeto gerenciado do doctrine?

Comment: Como assim? Você não quer ter que fazer esse processo que você descreveu? Poderia dar um exemplo do que seria esse "helper" que você deseja?

Comment: Exemplo:
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $article =$this->entityManager->find($id);
        $object = $this->geral('serialize')->deserialize($request->getContent(),Article:classe, 'json');

    // Aqui eu faço set em todas as propriedades de Article de object. Queria evitar isso entendeu?